# Why does DISTINCT show different results when using GROUP BY in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have the following 2 queries:

`SELECT id, sex FROM user WHERE sex=0 GROUP BY id LIMIT 10;` With the following output:

```
+----+-----+
| id | sex |
+----+-----+
|  3 |   0 |
|  6 |   0 |
| 30 |   0 |
| 36 |   0 |
| 38 |   0 |
| 40 |   0 |
| 43 |   0 |
| 46 |   0 |
| 48 |   0 |
| 54 |   0 |
+----+-----+
10 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

And

`SELECT DISTINCT id, sex FROM user WHERE sex=0 LIMIT 10;`

```
+------+-----+
| id   | sex |
+------+-----+
|  721 |   0 |
|  440 |   0 |
|  485 |   0 |
| 2388 |   0 |
| 1215 |   0 |
| 1218 |   0 |
| 6569 |   0 |
| 5123 |   0 |
| 5178 |   0 |
| 5177 |   0 |
+------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

But they show different results. What makes them create different results. I was under the impression that LIMIT was applied after everything was done. Could LIMIT be affecting this, or do DISTINCT and GROUP BY behave differently when trying to find unique/distinct values. Do they order them before outputting the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beause your query is not deterministic.
if you don't add an *order by* to your query, mysql chooses the data that is accessed the fastest way. if you change your query, mysql can change his execution plan, so other rows will be determined for fastest access.

if you want a deterministic (every time it should return the same) result, add an order by, that orders all business key (or primary key) columns in the proper order

this will be deterministic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, sex 
FROM user 
WHERE sex=0 
order by id
LIMIT 10
```

edit:
it's because GROUP BY implies an 'order by', distinct not, because group by has to "group" in a temporary table, so it can aggregate, meanwhile distinct ignores duplicate values

Comment: Thank you RomanKonz. But still why the difference between both. Which one is deterministic and which one is not. If both are not, which one is using what method to output the results in that order?

Comment: Thanks for the example RomanKonz but I want to know why the output was different, not just how to make it the same. Your answer is good by the way but I am curious to know why both created different results WITHOUT the ORDER BY. The "why" is the part I want.

Comment: but here, i posted this new thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629277/record-ordering-for-tables-with-no-indices

Answer (score 1):

because you are not using an ORDER BY clause.  if you use the ORDER BY clausweree, it would sort the resultset, which should return the same result in both cases

Comment: Hi foampile, can you read the comments I made for RomanKonz. Maybe you can help. Thanks.

Comment: do you have any indices, including constraints on the table?

Comment: Yes, another column "guid" is the index.