# Record ordering for tables with no indices

Tags: mysql, sql

I am curious how MySQL conducts internal record ordering in case there is no indices or constraints on a table.  Provided that the data contents never change, will the same SELECT always return the records in the same order or can you expect shuffled ordering?

Thanks

Comment: You can't rely on the SELECT to always return results in the same order. I don't know enough to describe in detail how MySQL stores its data, but I know that it may come up in a different order depending on many different criteria. Bottom line...I wouldn't "expect" shuffled ordering, but I definitely wouldn't count on it to not shuffle.

Comment: You should _never_ expect a query without an explicit `ORDER BY` to return with a deterministic order, even if there's a PK MySQL is likely to use for ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can expect order shuffling.  `ORDER BY` is critical.

Comment: what is it withing MySQL (or another RDBMS for that matter) that does determine how each query's results will be ordered?

Comment: I appreciated the question as a point of curiosity.  I think the answer is that robust RDBMS has more important things to do than explain itself.  But then, I find lots of clever ways to excuse my ignorance ... maybe that's all I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't create an Index the "last inserted will be the last displayed" that's not true at all if you make some update or, delete and insert into the table.  I.E if you delete and insert a record the order will start to messing(if you don't specify an order).  Also the index will not grant you a perfect order always, with HUGE TABLES, with A LOT of records you can't trust that the index will keep the order by itself (remember that the index can corrupt too) for that reason it's always recommended to use `order by` clausele